# Kafka connect jdbc source mssql server loading millions record throwing out of memory error

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have tried to load 77 millions of record from MSSQL server to Kafka topic through Kafka connect JDBC source.

Tried batch approach given batch.max.rows as 1000. In this case, after 1000 records, it's throughout of memory. Please share suggestions on how to make it works

Below are connector approach i tried

```
curl -X POST http://test.com:8083/connectors -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
        "name": "mssql_jdbc_rsitem_pollx",
        "config": {
                "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
                "connection.url": "jdbc:sqlserver://test:1433;databaseName=xxx",
                "connection.user": "xxxx",
                "connection.password": "xxxx",
                "topic.prefix": "mssql-rsitem_pollx-",
                 "mode":"incrementing",
                 "table.whitelist" : "test",
                "timestamp.column.name": "itemid",
         "max.poll.records" :"100",
                "max.poll.interval.ms":"3000",
                "validate.non.null": false
        }
        }'
```

```
curl -X POST http://test.com:8083/connectors -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
        "name": "mssql_jdbc_test_polly",
        "config": {
                "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
                "tasks.max": "10",
                "connection.url": "jdbc:sqlserver://test:1433;databaseName=xxx;defaultFetchSize=10000;useCursorFetch=true",
                "connection.user": "xxxx",
                "connection.password": "xxxx",
                "topic.prefix": "mssql-rsitem_polly-",
                 "mode":"incrementing",
                 "table.whitelist" : "test",
                "timestamp.column.name": "itemid",
                "poll.interval.ms":"86400000",
                "validate.non.null": false
        }
        }'
```

Answer (score 0):

try to increase Java heap size, write in command line:

`export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xms1g -Xmx2g"`

you can change the "Xmx2g" part to match your capacity.

Comment: Thanks ali, tried that above Heap_opts approach to increase it Xmx4g eventhough its not working, if we run the query in sqlserver normal select statement is take time. I think using kafka connect jdbc source we cant do this bulk load.